# textmate - change cursor color

Tags: macos, colors, themes, textmate

i'm using a theme for textmate which i really like but the cursor color is almost invisible.
**how do i change the color of the cursor?**
looking at the preferences, i don't see an option to change the color of the cursor.
anybody have any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never mind.
**Cursor == Caret.**